# Prolog addition excercise

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I have this very simple code as a representation of numerals. The problem is when I use the add2 function.

Example: `add2(s(0)+s(s(0)), s(s(0)), Z).` returns `s(s(s(s(s(0)))))` correctly. However `add2(0, s(0)+s(s(0)), Z).` always `returns s(0)+s(s(0))`. Can anyone see why this is happening?

```
numeral(0).
numeral(s(X)) :- numeral(X).
numeral(X+Y) :- numeral(X), numeral(Y).

add(0,X,X).
add(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z).

%%  exercise 1
add2(X,Y,R) :- add(X,Y,R).
add2(X+Y,Z,R) :- add(X,Y,A),add2(A,Z,R).
add2(X,Y+Z,R) :- add(Y,Z,A),add2(X,A,R).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because of the combination of the first `add2` clause and the first `add` clause. Your `add2(0, ..., ...)` will trigger `add(0, ..., ...)` which always unifies the second and third argument.

Answer (score 2):

In Prolog function symbols like the infix `+` are not evaluated. It seems you are trying to evaluate all occurrences of `+`. However, some of them are still not evaluated and this can be quite tricky if you try to do this ad hoc as in `add2/3`. Consider
`add2(0+0+0,0,R)` which fails with your definition.

What you call `numeral/1` might better be called `expression/1`.

Consider to define an auxiliary predicate `eval/2` to simplify expressions to s(X)-numbers.
Note however, that even such a definition will still fail for goals like `add2(0,0,0+0)`. This is an inherent problem which can only be solved using constraints or similar techniques...

Answer (score -1):

When you call `add2(0, s(0)+s(s(0)), Z)`, it will be unified with the first clause of `add2/3`, since this first clause only has three variables in the head, so it can be unified with any call of `add2/3`. This in turn will in your example lead to calling the first clause of `add/3`, so Z will be bound to `s(0)+s(s(0))`.

The problem with your code is that the more specific clauses of `add2/3` are placed after the general clause. So to make your code work, place the first clause of `add2/3` last, and add cuts to the other two, e.g.

```
add2(X+Y,Z,R) :- !,add(X,Y,A),add2(A,Z,R).
```

since when the head of that clause has matched the query, you're sure that you're executing the right clause and you won't have trouble on backtracking.

Comment: Well, this is a simple homework exercise, so I guess it's ok to require the input to be properly parenthesised (if that's the word...).

Comment: But: if you're really worried about cases like `add2(0+0+0,0,R)`, then replace the `add/3` calls in the two clauses of `add2/3` that handle the + operator with `add2/3` calls, e.g. `add2(X+Y,Z,R) :- !,add2(X,Y,A),add2(A,Z,R).`.

Comment: Consider adding `mul2/3` or a functor `(*)/2` to see why a separate definition makes sense - also as homework.

Comment: Sure, but that is probably quite quickly beyond the scope of his current homework. Also it distracts from the more basic problem that in his code the generic clause of `add2/3` was placed before the specific clauses. If one struggles with Prolog's basics than expecting him not only to solve the addition problem, but to write a generic expression parser/evaluator is quite ambitious.